# Jquery - Replace Specific Line in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm having an issue with iframes and IDs.

I currently have an Iframe with no ID attached to as its generated by another websites javascript. So I quickly wrote a Jquery script to give IDs to Iframes on load of page, and it worked successfully. Problem is however, it applies the ID to ALL the Iframes on the page instead of specifically the one I want.

This is what I have.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
$("iframe").attr({ 
  id: "iframeid1"
});
});</script>
```

Is there a method with Jquery to 'search and replace' something specific on the page? For example

**Search for:**

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="160" height="600"
```

**Replace with:**

```
<iframe id="iframeid1" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="160" height="600"
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: need more info about the html markup around the iframe. is the iframe wrapped inside a div? would be great if you can post the html around the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know it is the `nth` iframe on the page:

```
$("iframe")[n].setAttribute('id', 'iframe1');
```

EDIT: You could also use attribute selectors:

```
$("iframe[allowtransparency=true][frameborder=no][etc=etc]").attr({id: 'iframe1'});
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if there is a unique way of finding the iframe you want. For example, is it the only one with width = 160 and height = 600? Or is it always the Xth iframe on the page? Is it always located in the same spot in the page?

Here are some queries as examples for all 3 scenarios:

```
// if the width/height combination is unique...
var iframe = $('iframe[width=160][height=600]');

// if it is always, say, the 3rd iframe on the page
var iframe = $('iframe:eq(2)'); // 0-based index

// if it is always the only iframe in a div with an id of "iframeContainer"...
var iframe = $('#iframeContainer').find('iframe');
```

Then you can set the attribute like you said:

```
iframe.attr('id', 'iframeid1');
```

Answer (score 1):

if the iframe is wrapped inside a div, with a ID, than you can do:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
$("#divID iframe").attr({ 
  id: "iframeid1"
});
});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors to find an iframe tag with specific attributes.  But you need to be able to uniquely identify the specific iframe you want from attribute values, not HTML search.

As an example:

```
$('iframe[width="160"][height="600"]').attr("id", "iframeid1");
```

This would select iframe tags with width=160 and height=600.  You can add more attributes if needed to uniquely select your particular iframe.

Perhaps the best option would be to use the DOM structure around the iframe to identify which one you want.  You could use parent object identifiers, ordering of the tags, etc.. whatever helps uniquely identify the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you know where your iframe is at you can get it by index position.

If you have 4 iframes on the page and you're looking for the third (with respect to the DOM), you can do this:

```
$("iframe").get(3).attr({ 
  id: "iframeid1"
});
```